# ASP.NET Accessing Client Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

So I have spent almost all day researching for a solution to this question and have tried a multitude of things to no avail. First, let me set the situation up. The core solution I need is to access a user's Windows Credentials on a site hosted on IIS 6.1 Server. Everything else regarding access to pages and other role based functionality I have already handled. As a side note, this site is going to be accessed through an intranet and by far the primary browser IE9.

Now when running the project locally, something like 
`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` worked fine.

But, as mentioned in the premise of the problem, when a user accesses the site, that function is returning the server's window's credentials and not the users. (Specifically it was returning something like AppPool\Project)

So, I tried changing the IIS server settings. I disabled Anonymous Access, changed the apps configiration to Network Service, Enabled Windows Authentication, moved NTFM as the primary provider, changed the web config to have this:

```
           <system.web>
              <authentication mode="Windows"/>
             <identity impersonate="true"/>
           </system.web>
```

(I have tried changing impersonate to both true and false)

I have also tried different ways of returning the name of the user, like User.Identity, Environment.Name etc. etc.

Here is what I am trying to avoid:

- ASP.NET Default Windows Role Based Setup - This solution was used in another project, but the end users did not like receiving a login window when they did not have access to a page.
- Changing Internet Explorer Settings- During my research, I saw some solutions proposed changing the trusted sites. I do not have the ability to change this information and would like a solution that does not require a user to modify their IE settings (The option to use Integrated Windows Credentials is already checked for all users)

If anyone has a solution to this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I understand `<identity impersonate="true">` is supposed to do what you want. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: When setting Identity impersonate to true, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()= Anonymous
and 
 HttpContext.Current.User.Principal = NETWORKSERVICE

Comment: I should note that being Anonymous is disabled in the IIS website configuration